# How to mock a method that returns self in Python's unittest framework

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am using a class that has a method `shuffle` that returns a shuffled version of the instance calling it. This is:

`shuffled_object = unshuffled_object.shuffle(buffer_size)`

I would like to mock this method so that when it is called, it returns simply itself, without any shuffling. The following would be a simplification of this situation:

```
# my_test.py
class Test():

    def shuffle(self, buffer_size):
        return self
```

```
# test_mock
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mk

import my_test

def mock_test(self, buffer_size):
    return self

class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mock(self):
        with mk.patch('my_test.Test.shuffle') as shuffle:
            shuffle.side_effect = mock_test
            shuffled_test = my_test.Test().shuffle(5)
```

However, when I try this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: mock_test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'buffer_size'
```

The method is only being called with the argument `5`, the calling instance is not passing itself as the `self` argument to the method. Is it possible to achieve such a behavior with the `unittest.mock` module?

---

EDIT:

The real code would be something like:

```
# input.py
def create_dataset():
    ...
    raw_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_types, output_shapes)
    shuffled_dataset = raw_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
    dataset = shuffled_dataset.map(_load_example)
    ...
    return dataset
```

```
# test.py
def shuffle(self, buffer_size):
    return self

with mk.patch(input.tf.data.Dataset.shuffle) as shuffle_mock:
    shuffle_mock.side_effect = shuffle
    dataset = input.create_dataset()
```

The big issue here is that I want to mock only the `shuffle` method, because I do not want it to be random when testing, but I want to keep the rest of the original methods so my code can keep on working. The tricky part is that `shuffle` does not just shuffle the instance that called it, but it returns the shuffled instance, so I want to return instead the unshuffled version of the dataset when testing.

On the other hand, it is not so simple to make the mock inherit from `tf.data.Dataset` because as far as I understand it, `Dataset` seems to be an abstract class with abstract methods, and I want to abstract myself from whatever subtype of `Dataset` the initializer `from_generator` creates.

---

EDIT 2:

I have come a bit further by patching the method as follows:

```
def shuffle(cls, buffer_size, seed=None, reshuffle_each_iteration=None):
            def _load_example(example):
                return example
            return cls.map(cls, _load_example)

from data_input.kitti.kitti_input import tf as tf_mock

with mk.patch.object(tf_mock.data.Dataset, 'shuffle', classmethod(shuffle)):
    dataset = create_dataset()
```

Now the instance `raw_dataset` seems to be passing itself as the `self` argument of `shuffle`, but for whatever reason the code still crashes with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '_flat_types'
```

so I assume this `self` is somehow not exactly the calling instance, that it is somehow internally different.

Comment: What is what you want to test?

Comment: Usually one creates a random generator with a fixed seed value for such tests. Then it is ”random” but always the same in each test run.

Comment: @BlackJack That is also a possibility I considered, but that does not help with the fact that I still have to patch somehow the `shuffle` method so that I can give it a fixed seed only at testing time, unless there is something I am missing. Unfortunately I am not an expert with the `unittest` module yet :s

Comment: You don't want to assert anything?

Comment: @Goyo I do, that's why I am trying to create `dataset`, but that is not the part of my code I have problems with: the problems are with the section shown in the simplified snipped in my question.

Comment: Sure, your test is trying to change something that your code is trying to hide so they are fighting each other. Tthe best way to solve your problem is probably not doing that, but I can't suggest an alternative without knowing the actual purpose of the test.

Comment: @Goyo I would like to check whether `dataset` returns the correct elements when iterating over it or not, that's the reason why I want to eliminate the random component in the order in which the elements are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found a reasonable solution to my problem. Instead of trying to patch the `shuffle` method of `tf.data.Dataset`, I have thought that I could change it directly on the instance that is to be tested if I have access to it. Therefore, I have tried patching the method that creates the instance, `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`, so that it calls the original method, but before returning the newly created instance, it replaces its `shuffle` method by another one that simply returns the unaltered dataset. The code would be something as follows:

```
from_generator_old = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

def from_generator_new(generator, output_types, output_shapes=None, args=None):
    dataset = from_generator_old(generator, output_types, output_shapes, args)
    dataset.shuffle = lambda *args, **kwargs: dataset

    return dataset

from data_input.kitti.kitti_input import tf as tf_mock

with mk.patch.object(tf_mock.data.Dataset, 'from_generator', from_generator_new):
    dataset = input.create_dataset()
```

This seems to be working, but I am not sure if it's the right approach. If anyone has a better idea or can think of a reason why I should not be doing it this way, suggestions or other answers would be welcome, but so far I think this is the best option. If nobody proposes something better, I think I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

---

EDIT:

I have found a better solution for this problem. After a bit of reading around, I have come across an explanation about mocking unbound methods. Apparently, when `mock.patch.object` is used with the `autospec` parameter set to `True`, the signature of the patched method is maintained, calling the mock version of the method under the hood. This method would, then, become bound to the instance calling it (i.e. take the instance as the `self` argument). The explanation can be found under the following link:

https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/mock/examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods

When testing this, I also have found out that, when using the `tf.test.TestCase` class instead of `unittest.TestCase` for the tests, a random seed seems to be fixed for the whole computation graph, so the results of `shuffle` would be the same every time when tested under this framework. This does not, however, seem to be documented at all, so I am not sure whether it would be a good idea to blindly rely on this.

Answer (score 3):

## Why you don't have the self parameter

When declaring a class, the `function` you define is bound as `method` in your instances. Here is an instance of it:

```py
>>> def function():
...     pass
... 
>>> type(function)
<class 'function'>
>>> class A:
...     def b(self):
...         print(self)
>>> type(A.b)
<class 'function'>
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a.b)
<class 'method'>
# So you have the same behavior between the two following calls
>>> A.b(a)
<__main__.A object at 0x7f734511afd0>
>>> a.b()
<__main__.A object at 0x7f734511afd0>
```

## Solutions

I can propose a few solutions, not all compelling depending on your use and needs.

### Mock the Class

You can mock the whole class to override a function definition.
As seen before, this takes into account that you don't use an abstraction of the class.

```py
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mk

import my_test
import another

class TestMocked(my_test.Test):
    def shuffle(self, buffer_size):
        return self

@mk.patch("my_test.Test", TestMocked)
# Uncomment to mock the other file behavior
# @mk.patch("another.Test", TestMocked)
def test_mock():
    test_class = my_test.Test()
    shuffled_test = test_class.shuffle(2)
    print(my_test.Test.shuffle)
    # This is another file using your class,
    # You will have to mock it too in order to see the mocked behavior
    print(another.Test.shuffle) 
    assert shuffled_test == test_class
```

Wich will output:

```py
>>> from test_mock import test_mock
>>> test_mock()
<function TestMocked.shuffle at 0x7ff1f03f0ae8>
<function Test.shuffle at 0x7ff1f03f09d8>
```

### Call the function directly

I'm not fond of this one, as it makes you change the code for your tests.
You can transform your call from `instance.method()` to `class.method(instance)`. 
This will send the parameters as expected to your mocked function.

```py
# my_input.py
import tensorflow as tf


def data_generator():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield (i, [1] * i)


def create_dataset():
    _load_example = lambda x, y: x+y
    buffer_size = 3
    output_types = (tf.int64, tf.int64)
    output_shapes = (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None]))
    raw_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_types, output_shapes)

    shuffled_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.shuffle(raw_dataset, buffer_size)

    assert raw_dataset == shuffled_dataset
    assert raw_dataset is shuffled_dataset

    dataset = shuffled_dataset.map(_load_example)
    return dataset


# test_mock.py
import unittest.mock as mk
import my_input


def shuffle(self, buffer_size): 
    print("Shuffle! {}, {}".format(self, buffer_size))
    return self


with mk.patch('my_input.tf.data.Dataset.shuffle') as shuffle_mock:
    shuffle_mock.side_effect = shuffle
    dataset = my_input.create_dataset()
```

When run, you will have the following output:

```sh
$ python test_mock.py
Shuffle! (<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((), (?,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>, 3)
```

### Wrap the method use in a function

This is almost as the previous answer, but instead of calling the method from the class, you may be able to wrap it as follow:

```py
# my_input.py
import tensorflow as tf


def data_generator():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield (i, [1] * i)


def shuffle(instance, buffer_size):
    return instance.shuffle(buffer_size)


def create_dataset():
    _load_example = lambda x, y: x+y
    buffer_size = 3
    output_types = (tf.int64, tf.int64)
    output_shapes = (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None]))
    raw_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_types, output_shapes)

    shuffled_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.shuffle(raw_dataset, buffer_size)

    assert raw_dataset == shuffled_dataset
    assert raw_dataset is shuffled_dataset

    dataset = shuffled_dataset.map(_load_example)
    return dataset



# test_mock.py
import unittest.mock as mk
import my_input


def shuffle(self, buffer_size): 
    print("Shuffle! {}, {}".format(self, buffer_size))
    return self


with mk.patch('my_input.shuffle') as shuffle_mock:
    shuffle_mock.side_effect = shuffle
    dataset = my_input.create_dataset()
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought mocking the class would mock all of its methods, hiding all the other ones from the original class that I need to use as well. I have just tested it and it only overrides those methods defined in the mock class, which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I have just tried to apply this to my code and I have found out that not all of the methods are available when I mock the class. For example, in my case I am using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` to initialize my instance of a `tf.data.Dataset`, on which I am calling the `shuffle()` method that I want to mock. However, when I try to do that I get the following error:

`AttributeError: type object 'DatasetMock' has no attribute 'from_generator'`

So my mock class is not mocking the `from_generator` method for whatever reason. Any idea on why this might be so or how to overcome it?

Comment: The call to `patch` will simply replace the `Test` implementation with your `TestMock`, the class `TestMock` will behave like any other class so there shouldn't be a disparition of method. Could you update your question with the code you are using? Is your `DatasetMock` inheriting from `tf.data.Dataset` ?

Comment: Just updated the question with a more accurate description of the problem, I think it should be clearer now.

Comment: I've been testing your new solution in which you pass `raw_dataset` as the first argument to `shuffle`. The problem is that it works when you are mocking the method, because the instance is not passing itself as an argument, but when I run the real code without patching, the method `shuffle` will be called with the instance passing itself as the `self` argument, so `raw_dataset` (which is also the instance) would be taken as `buffer_size`, so the program crashes.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, that can't work like that. I got lost in my changes. The thing is that the `shuffle` method will be called as a function internally as I called it in the method `create_dataset`. So the difficulty would be to replace the internal shuffle method so that it is called with our `self`. Using `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle(raw_dataset, buffer_size)` should work in both cases, event if that is clearly not optimal.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it's not a bad idea. I think I am going to try and tinker around with it a bit see if I can get something better, though, because I would much rather not change my code because of testing, and also because I might face a similar problem in the future anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment

> I would like to check whether `dataset` returns the correct elements when iterating over it or not".

Clients of `create_dataset()` don't expect the elements to be in any particular order, they will be fine as long as all the expected elements and only the expected elements are there, whatever the order is. So that is what the test should be checking.

```
def test_create_dataset():
    dataset = create_dataset()
    assert sorted(dataset) == sorted(expected_elements)
```

The assertion might need to be more complex depending on the type of the values returned when iterating the dataset. For example it wouldn't work if the elements are `numpy` arrays or `pandas.Series`. In such cases you will need to use a custom key. This would work for `numpy` and `pandas` objects:

```
sorted(dataset, key=list)
```

Or you could use `set` or `collections.Counter`...

Now to address some of the concerns expressed in the comments:

> if you mean the `shuffle` function

Yes, the test wants to change the implementation of `.shuffle()` and the code is trying to hide it. That is making the test hard to write (that is why you had to come here to ask a question in the first place) and most likely hard to understand for future maintainers of the code (potentially including your future self). I would rather try to avoid it.

> as I said in the comments above I think it should be replaced to make the tests more robust/meaningful.

As a user of `create_dataset()` I don't know and I don't care about shuffling. It is meaningless to me. There is nothing like that in the way I call the function, it is just an implementation detail.

Making your test worry about that will make the test brittle, not more robust. If you change the implementation to not shuffling the data, or shuffling it without calling `Dataset.shuffle()`, I will still get the correct data but the test will fail. Why is that? Because it is checking stuff I don't care about. I would try to avoid that too.

> Isn't this, after all, the whole purpose of mocking? Making the outcome of some modules predictable in order to isolate the effects of the code you actually want to test?

Sure it is. Well, more or less. But the code you want to test (the function `create_dataset()`) has the shuffling hidden inside it as an implementation detail and coupled to the other behaviors, from the point of view of the caller there is nothing to isolate here. Now the test says no, I want to call `create_dataset()` but separate the shuffling behavior, and there is no obvious way of doing that and again that is why you came here to ask a question.

I would rather spare myself that trouble by making the code and the test agree on what behaviors should be decoupled from each other.

> I would much rather not change my code because of testing

Perhaps you should consider doing it. Tests can tell you about interesting uses of your code that you didn't anticipate. You wrote a test that wants to change the shuffling behavior. Is there a legitimate reason for other clients to want to do the same? Reproducible research is a thing, maybe having the seed as a parameter makes sense after all.

Comment: Hmm, it's an interesting idea, but there is something in the lack of traceability of the generated elements that does not fully convince me. What I mean is, there is a generator that creates non-unique elements, which are pre-processed (`_load_example`) and sent over to the `Dataset` instance that will return them as an iterator. If I just check whether the expected elements are there or not, I do not know whether each element from the generator yielded the correct element after processing, I just know that they were somehow generated from the collection of original elements.

Comment: A toy example could be the generated elements `2` and `4` and the processing function `lambda x: x % 4`, which would yield the `Dataset` elements `0` and `2`. If i were to change the processing function to `lambda x: (x + 2) % 4`, the test would still pass, because I would still be getting the correct elements, but the behavior is not as expected.

Comment: On the other hand, errors would not be traceable to the elements that produced them. In other words, I would not know which element from the generator yielded what error in the output, or whether the elements are generated as expected at all.

After a bit of thinking, this is my take on it. What are your thoughts on this? Do you reckon there's anything I am missing here?

Comment: @user3407000 It is your idea, not mine. If you want to test that the correct elements are returned then just test that. If you want to test something else then test something else. If your tests want to see or change something that the SUT is trying to hide you will have different parts of your code aiming for contradictory goals and that will make your life hard. Everything will be smoother if the tests and the production code work together towards a common goal instead of fighting each other.

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean by "see or change something that the SUT ist trying to hide". If you mean the `shuffle` function, as I said in the comments above I think it should be replaced to make the tests more robust/meaningful. I am not changing any functionality, only removing randomization. Isn't this, after all, the whole purpose of mocking? Making the outcome of some modules predictable in order to isolate the effects of the code you actually want to test?
Any thoughts or different points of view on this topic are more than welcome.